# Is it possible to save an encrypted data partition so that I can decrypt it later?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, encryption, unbricking

I have a rooted samsung galaxy s4 sph l720 with an encrypted data partition.
It's currently a soft brick.
I'm confident I could wipe the device and start over from scratch but then I'd lose everything in my internal data partition.

I have TWRP installed and the data partition reads as 0mb.
I know the password to access the data from the normal ROM startup but that's not an option in TWRP recovery.

I don't really care if I salvage the device. I have another device functioning as a phone right now.

I just can't believe there's no way to save this data.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen TWRP versions that ask for the FDE password and allow to access the encrypted data. May be there is also an updated TWRP version for your device available?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using 3.1.1-0 which as far as I know is the latest version for my device.  It is over 5 years old.

Comment: @Robert This version is the one provided for this device at the TWRP website so I believe it's the most up to date one. https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxys4sprint.html

Comment: Just copying the files and knowing the password likely won't be enough. I haven't done much with FBE but it likely also requires additional files with metadata. Without those the encrypted  files would be useless.